# Proving $8 | x^2 + y^2$ iff x,y are both even is false

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Per the question above I am trying to prove this statement false.  As such only one of two conditions have to be met both x and y being odd, or them both being odd.  I've seen a lot of examples on this site regarding x^2 - y^2 for a similar  example but none where they are added together so I was looking for a pointer on what I might be missing.  This is what I have so far:
False via contraposition: a^2 + b^2 is not divisible by 8 iff a or b are not even

Assume both a and b are odd
A = 2k + 1 and b = 2n + 1 where k and n are both integers

a^2 + b^2 = (2k + 1)^2 + (2n + 1)^2

a^2 + b^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 + 4n^2 + 4n + 1

a^2 + b^2 = 4(k^2 + k + n^2 + n) + 2 (not divisble by 8 so doesnt help the case)

Assume a is odd

A = 2k + 1 and b = 2n

x^2 = 4k(k + 1) + 1
k(k + 1) is even (product of 2 numbers)

x^2 is of form 8k + 1

a^2 + b^2 = 8x + 1 + 8y + 1

a^2 + b^2 = 8(x - y) + 2  (the extra 2 is stoping this case from being true as well)

Comment: To prove false, a counterexample suffices:  $8$ does not divide $2^2+4^2$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Wouldn't we have to provide a counterexample where x^2 + y^2 is divisible by 8 though?

Comment: @Tunifish17 It's only a counterexample if it makes the statement false. Otherwise it's just an example (which is not helpful if you're trying to disprove the statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to disprove the statement

> $$8\mid x^2+y^2\iff 2\mid x, y $$

As @J.W. Tanner pointed out in the comments, a simple counterexample - such as $2^2+4^2$ or its generalization $(2n)^2+(2n+2)^2=8n^2+8n+4\not\equiv 0\pmod 8$ - is enough. This proves that $$2\mid x, y\color{red}{\not\Rightarrow}8\mid x^2+y^2$$

However, you won't be able to disprove the other direction, since it is true $$8\mid x^2+y^2\color{red}{\implies}2\mid x,y$$ This follows from the fact that the only quadratic residues modulo $8$ are $\{0, 1, 4\}$.

Comment: I think I am missing something since doesnt this just prove what we were trying to  prove was false? aka that x and y must be even in order to be divisible by 8?

Comment: I fact, $x$ and $y$ have to be even in order $x^2+y^2$ to be divisible by $8$

Comment: However, the other direction is wrong, i.e. being even doesn't imply that they will be divisible by $8$

Comment: due to the fact that x and  y both have to be even in order to be divisible by 8 wouldnt that make the original question true and thus not able to be proved false?

Comment: No, because you said *iff*. The statement "$8\mid x^2+y^2$" implies that $x,y$ are even is, however, correct.

Comment: by saying that x,y are divisible by 8 only when they are even proves the opposite of what we wanted? I might just be thinking of this too literally since its not clicking for me